# combine date and time into a single datetime

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a date and time control, which I would like to concatenate

```
var startDate = jQuery('#startDatepicker').find("input").val();
var startTime = jQuery('#startTimepicker').find("input").val();
```

I have another var field which has data as below:

```
var targetTime = new Date().setMinutes(-5).valueOf();
```

startDatepicker has the value as : 02/06/2017

startTimepicker, currentTime has the value as : 05:17 am

targetTime has the value as: 1486374940591

I want to concatenate startdate and starttime in the format of targetTime. How to concatenate the start date and start time?
Thanks

Comment: Don't you need to use `getMinues` value in `setMinutes` ?

Comment: use var s = new Date(year,month,date) and then s.setHours() and s.setMinutes() then can parse as Date.parse(s)

Comment: Hi @Rayon.. the targetTime data is correct. I want to concatenate startDate and startTime in the format of targetTime, so that i can do a comparison

Comment: @venkat14 — As Vinod said, Use `var s = new Date(year,month,date)` to get JS Date Object and if your target is to get TimeStamp then ___`DateObject.getTime()`___ will help :)

Comment: Hi @Rayon. I am sorry, but did not get this. I have the date field in the variable StartDate, time field in the variable startTime. How to achieve the logic informed by vinod louis for those variables

Comment: @venkat14 — You will have to split the input data to get separate `months, days, year, hours, minutes, seconds` etc....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass your date and time to this function. It will return the Date object. Use getTime() on that to get the desired result. [Codepen example.](http://codepen.io/shahabaz/pen/BpOdJV)

```
function getAsDate(day, time)
{
 var hours = Number(time.match(/^(\d+)/)[1]);
 var minutes = Number(time.match(/:(\d+)/)[1]);
 var AMPM = time.match(/\s(.*)$/)[1];
 if(AMPM == "pm" && hours<12) hours = hours+12;
 if(AMPM == "am" && hours==12) hours = hours-12;
 var sHours = hours.toString();
 var sMinutes = minutes.toString();
 if(hours<10) sHours = "0" + sHours;
 if(minutes<10) sMinutes = "0" + sMinutes;
 time = sHours + ":" + sMinutes + ":00";
 var d = new Date(day);
 var n = d.toISOString().substring(0,10);
 var newDate = new Date(n+"T"+time);
 return newDate;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

This do what you need

```
var date = new Date(startDate + ' ' + startTime);
```

```js
jQuery('#startDatepicker, #startTimepicker').on('input', function() {
  var startDate = jQuery('#startDatepicker').val();
  var startTime = jQuery('#startTimepicker').val();
  var date = new Date(startDate + ' ' + startTime);
  console.log(date)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Date
<input id="startDatepicker">Time
<input id="startTimepicker">
```